# Import group price from CSV files for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, price, import, group

Import group price from CSV files for Magento ,
Hi Please help me to import Group price in magento

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail, have you tried to import product data? You come across any specific errors etc. Your question is too generic!

Comment: hi, i need to upload bulk product with group price, But not able to import with default importer, Do you have a any script or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple custom module to perform customer group price. Take inspiration from https://goo.gl/nFxQ6D code to create the module.

Comment: But , Where is the example CSV File

Comment: Attached CSV not working. i have already checked,